# If $\{f_n\}\subset L^P(X) $ converges to a function $f \in L^p(X)$ then exists a subsequence $\{ f_{n_{k}} \}$ that converges a.e. to ${f}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that if I have a sequence $\{f_n\}\subset L^P(X),1 \le p<+\infty, \{f_n\}$ converges to a function $f \in L^p(X)$ then exists a subsequence $\{ f_{n_{k}} \}$ that converges a.e. to ${f}$

X is a positive measure space

To prove this have I to consider the proof of RieszFischer' theorem?

Comment: by $f_{n}$ converges to $f\in L^{p}$, you mean they convergence in $L^{p}$ or poinwise converges to some $L^{p}$ integrable function?

Comment: they converge in $L^p$.There's is the suggestion of follow the proof of the completeness Lp spaces

Comment: @GiuliaB. Is my answer clear to you?

Comment: It's not clear because the proof of the completeness Lp space is with p-norm

Comment: This doesn't have to do anything with completeness.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Show that $f_n \stackrel{\mu}{\to} f$, i.e. $f_n\to f$ in measure.

**Proof:** $$\mu(\{|f_n-f| > \epsilon\}) = \int I_{\{|f_n-f| > \epsilon\}}\leq \int |f_n-f|^p/\epsilon^p d\mu \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0\quad \square$$

(2) Then use that a sequence that converges in measure has an almost surely convergent subsequence.

**Proof**: Choose a subsequence $(n_k)_k$ with $n_k \nearrow \infty$ such that $\mu(|f_{n_k}-f| > 1/k) \leq 1/k^2$ for $k \geq 1$. Then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is $k_\epsilon \geq 1$ such that

$$\sum_{k=k_\epsilon}^\infty\mu(\{|f_{n_k}-f| > \epsilon\}) < \infty$$

which obviously implies $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.s. $\quad \square$

Comment: That answer only gives the proof for a finite measure space though

Comment: Read the comments under the answer. Finiteness is not necessary.

Comment: @ε-δ I think to show $(1)$, you do need it to have finite total measure, since you need to use Egorov.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical, no it is easy to see the contrapositive statement using just the definitions

Comment: I added proofs to both my claims. I don't need finiteness anywhere.

Comment: I think the OP does not say $f_{n}$ converges to $f$ in $L^{p}$, but pointwise? He just said that $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to a function $f$ and $f$ is $L^{p}$ integrable.

Comment: If it converges pointwise, there is nothing to prove. Just take the sequence itself, which is a subsequence that converges almost surely. @JacobsonRadical

Comment: @ε-δ yes you are right. I was dumb.